# Using Piezzo Electric buzzer 10V with an Arduino Lilypad USB

Tags: usb, voltage-level, piezo, buzzer

I bought a 10 V Piezzo electric buzzer and I wonder how to connect it to an Arduino (in my case a Lilypad USB, but the question stands for any Arduino I guess...).
I hadn't realized this was a 10V buzzer, whereas the Arduino will support at most 5V.

I tried a simple layout such as below, with [the sample code from a sparksfun tutoral](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sik-experiment-guide-for-arduino---v32/experiment-11-using-a-piezo-buzzer), but that's not working!

[image: lilypad connected to buzzer]

So, how can I do it? ... or should I use another buzzer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your options:

1. Try it anyway with 5V: the buzzer might still produce loud enough sounds for your needs.
2. Use the line from the arduino to drive an "amplifying" stage (ex: 2N2222 in ON/OFF mode) - but this will also require a 10V source (like a step-up voltage converter)
3. Get a piezo that is designed to operate at 5V

Comment: I'll try next week-end and let you know, thanks.

Comment: I haven't managed to get any sound, but I'm probably doing it wrong.

I connected the buzzer to output pin 9 (and the other one to GND), and used [the code here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sik-experiment-guide-for-arduino---v32/experiment-11-using-a-piezo-buzzer) : no sound.
I also tried with another 5V buzzer : no sound.